# sunspot/solr multiple indices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I have sunspot/solr set up to search products on my site. We need the ability to search users and another model (too much to explain what this is) in out app. Basically there is form for searching product via solr and this works well. There would be another form for searching users and the other form to search the other model.

I assume it is recommended to have a separate index for products, users, and the other model? It's seems best to keep the index from getting too bloated? Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the models are indexed in the same index. And sunspot will also index the classnames into the index.

Comment: So there is no reason to force it to have separate indices? The reason being that if you're searching for "users" there is no reason to go through all those other "product" records.

Comment: @isea if you are using sunspot's search api such as User.search, it will add a query condition such as classname = 'User', so it would't go through other kinds of records.